# Peut-on mettre l'expression bouche bée au pluriel ?

Tags: expressions, pluriel

La phrase suivante est-elle correcte ?

> Deux enfants les regardaient passer, bouches bées, les yeux exorbités.

Ou bien faut-il laisser *bouche bée* au singulier ?

Comment: `nom et adjectif` au singulier donne `noms et adjectifs` au pluriel. Pas d'exemple au pluriel ni de contre indication dans le petit Robert pour `bée`. Pluriel, surtout s'ils ont les yeux exorbités. Au singulier avec `l'oeil exorbité` pourrait s'entendre aussi, cela concernerait alors leur attitude.

Comment: À propos d'une expression analogue dans un autre contexte, l'usage préfère le _choeur à bouche fermée_ dans Madame Butterfly et dans Carmen.

Comment: NGrams de [bouches bées](http://bit.ly/1MCTpTT), suivez les liens pour voir les exemples en contexte.

Answer (score 6):

Au choix.

- *Bouche bée* décrit leur expression (commune).
- *Bouches bées* décrit la scène.

Answer (score 2):

Je l'écrirais plutôt au singulier : chaque enfant a une seule bouche.

> Deux enfants les regardaient passer, bouche bée, les yeux exorbités.

De la même manière, on dit :

> Les deux enfants étaient le nez au vent.

On n'emploie pas le pluriel car chaque enfant a un seul nez.

Comment: *Les deux z-enfants étaient nez z-au vent, bouches z-ouvertes et mentons z-imberbes, seuls au milieu de la pampa* ?

Answer (score 2):

D'accord, le singulier "bouche bée" semble l'emporter, et je ne suis pas contre. Cependant, il me semble que le pluriel est aussi admissible aussi pour deux raisons. D'abord, il ne choque pas l'oreille; le pluriel et le singulier se prononcent de la même manière. Deuxio, le pluriel "yeux" avoisinant rend le pluriel "bouches" vraisemblable. J'estime donc qu'il n'y a pas de mal à mettre le pluriel

Comment: On peut s'en convaincre aisément avec une comparaison: 

"Les chiens, l'oeil luisant, regardaient l'étal du boucher"
ou bien
"Les chiens, les yeux luisants, regardaient...."

Ainsi pourquoi pas "Les enfants les regardaient passer, bouches bées, yeux grand ouverts..."

Comment: Le fait que "cela ne choque pas l'oreille" n'est pas un argument, surtout quand il n'y a pas de différences à l'oreille. A ce moment-là "on a pas..." (au lieu de "on n'a pas...") est correct car cela ne choque pas l'oreille !

Comment: Si le fait qu'une chose inaudible ne peut pas constituer un argument est une excellente idée, rejeter les seuls arguments linguistiquement valables, les différences audibles entre les énoncés grammaticaux et non-grammaticaux ne semble pas en être une. L'absence généralisée des *ne* à l'oral n'est pas limitée aux contextes après *on* loin de là.

Answer (score 0):

Oui, ils ont chacun une bouche.

Answer (score -2):

"Être bouche bée" est une expression. Bé ou Bée n'est pas un adjectif. D'après l'académie française "bée" n'est utilisé que dans l'expression "bouche bée".

Comment: C'est bien beau, mais ça ne répond pas directement à la question! Pourrais-tu développer un peu plus!

Comment: Techniquement, si, [bée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%A9e) est toujours un adjectif féminin, même si il ne s'emploie en effet plus que dans cette expressions

Comment: Et même si *bée* n'était pas un adjectif mais le participe passif de *[béer](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/beer)* comme *béant* est son participe présent, en quoi celà empêcherait-il l'accord ?